# Is the pyrolysis of tetrachloroaluminate(III) anion possible?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, pyrolysis

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_tetrafluoroborate) says that lithium tetrafluoroborate decomposes to lithium fluoride and boron trifluoride when heated. Does the same hold for sodium tetrachloroaluminate (all anhydrous) as well?

Answer (score 6):

Unlike lithium tetrafluoroborate $\ce{LiBF4},$ sodium tetrachloroaluminate $\ce{NaAlCl4}$ doesn't decompose upon melting, and doesn't show any signs of decomposition or phase transition up to approx. $\pu{800 °C}$ [[1](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jct.2004.04.011), p. 688]:

> [image: (NaCl + AlCl3) phase diagram at 0.1 MPa]
>
> FIGURE 3. Calculated $(\ce{NaCl + AlCl3})$ phase diagram at $\pu{0.1 MPa}$ (dotted lines are liquid–liquid miscibility gap boundary and monotectic at $P > \pu{0.1 MPa}).$

Molten sodium tetrachloroaluminate is used as electrolyte in [ZEBRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molten-salt_battery#Sodium%E2%80%93nickel_chloride_(Zebra)_battery) batteries with normal operating temperature range of $\pu{270–350 °C}.$

#### References

1. Robelin, C.; Chartrand, P.; Pelton, A. D. Thermodynamic Evaluation and Optimization of the $(\ce{NaCl + KCl + AlCl3})$ System. *The Journal of Chemical Thermodynamics* **2004**, 36 (8), 683–699. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jct.2004.04.011.